# New to Xcode how to create a class

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

Hi all I have currently started using xcode and objective C and I just want to know how to create a specific class within my program.

Comment: CMD+N.  Thank me later.

Comment: All questions stay in the Unanswered queue until the Asker (you) mark as accepted.  If this question is not fully answered, please update your question or clarify with a comment.

Comment: Why is this not constructive? Actually there is no way to add a c++ class in Xcode which is weird. The answer below adds objective-c class not c++ class.

Answer (score 14):

Here are the steps to add a new class.

[image: New File]
[image: Objective-C class]
[image: Name the new class]
[image: Check the box for the target]
[image: See the new class files]

Comment: This is to add objective-c class, how can I add c++ class? Thx

Comment: Instead of choosing the Cocoa Touch category, you can choose the C and C++ category.

Comment: I upgraded to xcode 5.2 and this option is there. It was missing in 4.3 version.

Comment: In Xcode 6, it's not anymore "Cocoa Touch" -> "Objective-C Class", but instead "Source" -> "Cocoa Touch Class". It does exactly the same thing as described in the above answer.