# new to IOS, is there a new way to create classes in Xcode 4.6.2

Tags: ios

my tutorial might be a bit outdated, it states to create a class like this:

```
@interface Person: NSObject

{
NSString *name;
int age;

}

//method declaration
-(NSString *)name;
-(int)age;


@end
```

but, it seems like classes are now being created like this in the new version of Xcode:

```
@implementation Person: NSObject

@end
```

do i understand this correctly ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15283627/new-to-xcode-how-to-create-a-class  see this post

Comment: Visit [Ray wender lich](http://raywenderlich.com). this site has good tutorial for newbies.

Comment: but why does my tutorial show something different on how to create a class? is it still being done like this ?

Comment: the ways you created class is alright.

Comment: Actually, you may be right that the compiler will now let that second construct through.  They keep throwing in new, poorly-documented "features" with every release.  But the old way is the "canonical" one.

Answer (score 1):

Those are two halves of a class, neither alone is a class.

A class consists of an interface file, `Class.h`, and an implementation file, `Class.m`.

The Interface is used to declare your class including public properties, variables, and methods.

```
@interface Person: NSObject

@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *name;
@property (nonatomic, readwrite) int age;

- (void)aMethod;

@end
```

The Implementation is used to actually carry out your declarations. This is the meat of your class.

```
@implementation Person

- (id)init
{
    self = [super init];
    if (self) {
        // Set Defaults
        self.name = @"Default Name";
        self.age = 0;
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)aMethod
{
    // Do Something
}

@end
```

Answer (score 0):

the @interface part is in the header (.h) file meanwhile the @implementation part is in the .m file.

Answer (score 0):

use this site

http://www.ios-developer.net/iphone-ipad-programmer/development/classes/creating-a-new-class

this will helpful i think..